# Reg exp to replace the whole word if any word contains any non alphanumeric character or space

Tags: php, regex, cpu-word, preg-replace, alphanumeric

e.g

string = "This is a re@lly long long,long! sentence";

becomes

string = "This is a long sentence";

Basically so all non-alphanumeric words or removed keeping spaces in tacked

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
preg_replace("/(^|\\s)\\S*?[^ a-zA-Z0-9]\\S*?(\\s|$)/", '$1', $string)
```

Comment: Almost any time you use `a-z`, you’ve made a mistake.

Comment: because it assumes a 7-bit ASCII world from the 1960s.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this is quite intuitive:

```
<?php

$text = "This is a #@^!%$ re@lly long long,long! sentence";
print preg_replace("/\\w*[^\\w\\s]\\w*\\s*/", "", $text);

?>
```

The output is ([as seen on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/3mUDY)):

```
This is a long sentence
```

This works by matching any sequence of `\w*` that is followed by `[^\w\s]` (neither a word character nor a whitespace), followed by any sequence of `\w*\s*`. Anything matching this can be deleted, so it's replaced with `""`.

#### See also

- [regular-expressions.info/Character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)